# how to process xml tags with same name but different attribute values in xslt using for loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Sampletest.xsl"?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="System_Id">Saranya</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Case_ID">1234</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Case_Submitter_ID">samandav</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="System_Id">Gayathri</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Case_ID">5678</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Case_Submitter_ID">garaghur</COLUMN>  
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//ROW">
<businessobject>
     <fulltext>
             <title><xsl:value-of select="//COLUMN[@NAME='Title']"/></title>
             <id><xsl:value-of select="//COLUMN[@NAME='Case_ID']"/></id>
             <nccode><xsl:value-of select="//COLUMN[@NAME='System_Id']"/></nccode>
     </fulltext>
</businessobject>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have the problems in fetching values of different rows using for loop, I get the values of first row in all the rows. I am trying fetch values of all rows from XML. Can anyone help me in this. 
Thanks In Advance:)

Comment: I guess you have to provide source XML. Use 4 or more spaces indentation to keep XML formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW">
      <businessobject>
        <fulltext>
             <title><xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='Title']"/></title>
             <id><xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='Case_ID']"/></id>
         <nccode><xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='System_Id']"/></nccode>
        </fulltext>
      </businessobject>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there is no COLUMN[@NAME='Title'] in your input example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `//` in your XPath means: search for all these elements through complete file. If you can you should always use `/`.

Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//COLUMN[@NAME='Title']"/>
```

To:

```
<xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='Title']"/>
```

You can even change more and go more relative:

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ROW">
```

To:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW">
```